# c# exception “not all code path return a value”

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi all I have a method to update my MySQL. I'm using a MS Visual Studio

```
public static User updateUser(string name, string passwd)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        string query = "UPDATE USER SET Name='" + name +, Password='" + pass + "' ";
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
  }
```

the above returns an error saying  not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Public static `User` Method(), you see your problem? change that `User` With `void` if you don't want to return an object of that class.

Comment: Side note: this code is a disaster waiting to happen. No using blocks around connection and string concatenations in query text and how many users do you plan to update with this query?.

Comment: **Warning!!!** Code is opened to **SQL Injection**

Comment: Indeed, when you encounter the user [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) you'll have fun...

Answer (score 1):

According to your code , the method method is not returning anything, You need to return the User Object.

If you do not want to return anything, you could just change the method implementation as follows,

```
public void updateUser(string name, string passwd)
```

Alternatively you could return boolean to know whether row updated or not. return true when ExecuteNonQuery return >0, otherwise return false